# Why was this question asking for improvements to a regex closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42560447/1222951) was closed as "off topic". I fail to understand the reasoning behind this.

Specifically, the chosen reason was

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers.

The question is neither asking for debugging help, nor does it lack a clear problem statement. The asker is well aware that their regex isn't up to the task, and they are asking for help in improving it. The problem statement is clear: "I want to match `www.` but only if not preceded by `http://`". We see dozens if not hundreds of people asking for improvements to their regex every day and they're not usually considered off topic.

Perhaps some of the users who voted to close the question chose a more suitable reason, but I have no way of knowing.

One person, who shall remain anonymous, tried to explain the reason to me. They said "The issue is not reproducible without the OP's code". This baffled me. We only need to [paste the regex into an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/Vgkj1s/1) and we can clearly see that the OP's regex matches `www.` even if it is preceded by `http://`. Regex is a powerful tool, so there often is no need for any code. This question is no exception. The fact that there is an [accepted answer with absolutely no code in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42560684/1222951) is proof of this.

---

I agree that the question is not *good*. One could argue that it shows little effort. However, I strongly disagree with it being closed. I see no reason to prevent users from posting answers.

Comment: These kind of "write my code for me" questions seem to be acceptable in the [regex] tag.  But he also used [c#] and [.net], they don't put up with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a regex in that question?

The question itself - discounting *all* comments - doesn't appear to have any sort of regular expression that the OP has tried.  The OP even claims to have known how to match `www.`, but again, no code exists to back this assertion up.

Here's where I agree with you:  the question *probably* shouldn't have been closed with that reason.  They may make mention of code, but since none exists, it's too broad.

Here's where I disagree with you: the question *needs* to be closed.  Just because it looks like a simple enough question doesn't mean that it's entirely answerable.  It could easily be the case that the OP has a typo in their regex (easily solved with another close message/comment), or the OP is looking to get us to do their work for them (solved *only* by closure).  We don't want to answer questions in which there is no noticeable effort - that is, the question is almost entirely "do X for me" - because it gives other users the impression that we as volunteers are willing to do that.

Comment: In any case, [it's a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081294/regex-to-match-a-pattern-as-long-as-it-is-not-preceded-by-a-different-pattern), of [multiple questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207256/how-do-i-match-part-of-a-string-only-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-certain-characters), really [multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970643/how-can-i-use-regex-to-match-a-character-when-not-following-a-specific-chara). The canonical [being this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else).

Comment: @Tunaki:  I'm not willing to say that the question you linked to was the canonical, since the original question is in C#, and I'm not 100% sure if C# and Java's regex engines are 100% compatible with each other.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed the last one was Java. The others aren't.

Comment: How do I close these comments as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538579/are-java-and-c-sharp-regular-expressions-compatible ?

Comment: Yep @Will; that's what I thought.  I don't venture far off of the Java mountain, and didn't have time this morning to look into it.

Comment: @Tunaki That's a good point. I didn't think of it as a dupe. That's certainly a valid reason for closing it.

Comment: @Rawing Duplicate is really the close reason for those questions (and for lots of others) to me. Before thinking of answering any questions, duplicates always have to be considered.

Comment: I thought of the question as a "I don't know how to do this, please help me" sort of question rather than a "I need help making this regex work" question. That's why I think it's silly to insist that the OP include their regex in the question. Of course that makes it a "do X for me" sort of question, but really, that's what a lot of regex question are like. It's normal that people are confused by regex and need someone to "do their work for them" because they don't know how to even start. But I can understand your point of view. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> The question is neither asking for debugging help

They have a regex, that regex isn't working properly for them.  That sure sounds like a question about debugging help.

> nor does it lack a clear problem statement

But it does.  It just says that their solution doesn't work.  It doesn't say why it doesn't work, whether it fails, doesn't match properly (and if so, how) etc.  Without knowing what the problem is with their solution, we can't fix it.

> The asker is well aware that their regex isn't up to the task, and they are asking for help in improving it.

And given that, they *need to actually post it* along with a description of what the problem with it is.  If they don't, we can't help them fix the problems it has.

> We only need to paste the regex into an online regex tester and we can clearly see that the OP's regex

The OP never provided any regex, so no, we can't put the regex that they never posted into an online regex tester.

Comment: Okay, technically the OP never posted their regex. But do we _really_ need to insist that they add the 5 characters `www\.` to their question? Is _that_ what "showing effort" means? I also disagree with the statement "Without knowing what the problem is with their solution, we can't fix it". In my opinion, that's not what the question was about. The OP didn't ask "why does my regex not work", they simply asked for a regex that does work.

Comment: @Rawing You don't actually know that that was their regex, so...yes, you do actually need to ask that they post the regex that is causing them problems.  That's how you can know exactly what their problem is, and how to fix it.  When you just guess at what their code is, you can guess wrong.

Comment: @Rawing The other problem is that you could very well suggest a regex that works, only to find out the OP used that regex, but didn't use it correctly (maybe they specified the incorrect `RegexOptions` enum or they're looking at `.Groups` instead of `.Matches`; I don't know, I don't have enough rep to see the question). So, it's possibly not just five characters; it's the entire way they are using the code that matters.